# Statistical distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to figure out what kind of distribution the following statement is: Each time a webpage is loaded, one of these twenty problems is chosen at
random. If the webpage is loaded 20 times, what is the probability this problem
will not be loaded?

I initially thought it was negative binomial, but I am having a hard time figuring out what the parameters would be.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(\frac{19}{20}\right)^{20} = \left( 1 + \frac{-1}{20} \right)^{20}.
$$
This would be roughly $\dfrac 1 e \approx \dfrac 1 {2.71828\ldots}$ since $\left( 1 + \dfrac a n \right)^n \to e^a$ as $n\to\infty$, and this is the case $a=-1$, and we're talking $20$ to be "approximately $\infty$".